# How do I extract the "href" attributes from a HTML document with select.rs?

Tags: http, rust

I am trying to write a very basic crawler. After receiving an HTTP response, I am using the [select.rs](https://github.com/utkarshkukreti/select.rs) crate to extract the URLs from the body for further crawling.

How can I extract these URLs from from the "document" which is the "body" part of the HTTP response using the "for-iteration"?

```
extern crate hyper;
extern crate select;
extern crate xhtmlchardet;
extern crate robotparser;
extern crate url;

use std::io::Read;
use Crawler::hyper::client::Client;
use Crawler::hyper::header::Connection;
use Crawler::select::document::Document;
use Crawler::select::predicate::*;

pub fn crawl(url: &str) {

    //Opens up a new HTTP client
    let client = Client::new();

    //Creates outgoing request
    let mut res = client.get(&*url)
        .header(Connection::close())
        .send().unwrap();

    //Reads the response
    let mut body = String::new();
    res.read_to_string(&mut body).unwrap();

    println!("Response: {}", res.status);
    println!("Headers:\n{}", res.headers);
    println!("Body:\n{}", body);


    let document = Document::from_str(&*body);

    for node in document.find(Attr("id", "hmenus")).find(Name("a")).iter() {
        println!("{} ({:?})", node.text(), node.attr("href").unwrap());
    }
}
```

The result of executing crawl for a URL like "um.ac.ir" is a full HTTP response with a body. I am trying to extract the `href`s from this output.

```
Response: 200 OK
Headers:
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Cache-Control: cache
Date: Tue, 27 Feb 2018 13:16:27 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Pragma: no-cache
Server: GFW/2.0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; preload
Set-Cookie: POSTNUKESID=pnd2nuadgastqak5h6nop87c63; path=/

...

<div class="col-md-4">
    <h3>سایر</h3>
    <ul> 
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://ftpnews.um.ac.ir/">سایت خبری ftp دانشگاه</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://news.um.ac.ir/Topic96.html">گزینش دانشگاه </a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://herasat.um.ac.ir/index.php?lang=fa">مدیریت حراست دانشگاه </a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mafakher.um.ac.ir/">مركز آثارمفاخر و اسناد دانشگاه</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://intr.um.ac.ir/">مدیریت همكاری های علمی و بین المللی</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://eva.um.ac.ir/"> مدیریت نظارت و ارزیابی دانشگاه</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://saybanemehr.um.ac.ir/">سایت سایبان مهر</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://faf.um.ac.ir/">بنیاد دانشگاهی فردوسی</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://ads.um.ac.ir/">آگهي ها و تبليغات دانشگاه</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://fumblog.um.ac.ir/">سامانه مدیریت وبلاگ</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://basijasatid.um.ac.ir/">بسیج اساتید</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://basij.um.ac.ir/">بسیج كاركنان</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://nahad.um.ac.ir/">نهاد نمایندگی رهبری در دانشگاه</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>

...
```

The problem is that the `println!("{} ({:?})", node.text(), node.attr("href").unwrap())` doesn't output anything since the `[...].iter()` is not working correctly:

```
for node in document.find(Attr("id", "hmenus")).find(Name("a")).iter() {
        println!("{} ({:?})", node.text(), node.attr("href").unwrap());
    }
```

It seems that `find(Attr("id", "hmenus")).find(Name("a"))` isn't the right way for finding "href" tags from the body of the HTTP response.

I believe rewriting this part should fix the problem in my code, although it requires an overall knowledge of how `select::document` is working.

Comment: You have forgotten to state what the *problem* with your code is. On the surface, it looks like it would work.

Comment: The problem is with the last part, as i mentioned i need help writing the "for-iteration" part of my code.

Comment: You've *already* written that part though. From your code: `for node in document.find(Attr("id", "hmenus")).find(Name("a")).iter()`. That is a for loop. It iterates. It is unclear exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Well i edited the question accordingly and specified the problem in "for-iteration" part of the code, sorry for the misunderstanding, i hope it helps.

Comment: *it seems that [...] isn't the right way* — but **why** does it not "seem" like the right way? Are you getting a compilation error, a runtime error, incorrect/malformed data, etc.? *I believe rewritting this part should fix the problem* — you still haven't said what the problem you are getting *is*.

Comment: There is absolutely no compilation error, the problem here is that the `println!("{} ({:?})", node.text(), node.attr("href").unwrap())` doesn't output anything since the `[...].iter()` is not working correctly.
The problem is not with compile/runtime errors, the problem is my lack of knowledge to work with `select.rs` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you copied the `Attr("id", "hmenus")` from some example code. This is a filter predicate that matches an HTML node containing attribute `id="hmenus"`. Your example page um.ac.ir does not contain any nodes with attribute `id="hmenus"`. If you want the crawler to find **all** <a> nodes on the page, the filter predicate would be `Name("a")`.

```
for node in document.find(Name("a")).iter() {
    if let Some(href) = node.attr("href") {
        println!("{} ({:?})", node.text().trim(), href);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this code solved my problem.